# Javascript , adding hour onto watch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, raphael

Hi guys playing around with javascript and raphael. I am actually pretty close to finishing my game of for my website but i just have a little problem with a function.

I have made a clock which tells the time . I am trying to make it so when the user clicks on a button it actually adds an extra hour onto the clock. Hopefully when i figure this out i can then start to make it so the user can add minutes is well but one step at a time. I have tried a lot of different versions but i cant seem to get the code to run. I think i am on the right path, if anyone could look and give me some help that would be great.

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/WEaFx/16/)

As you can see i have made some functions at the top to try and add an hour everytime the user clicks on the right hand side button and at the same time the left hand side button will reset the time back to normal.

```
    if(hou >= 24)
    {
        hou-= 24;   
    }
```

Also used some simple code to make sure it does not go over the 24 hour peroid so it dosen't hit like 35:22:12 etc. But for some reason the buttons are not working. Any help on this area would be great. Thanks

Comment: The value of incHour is increasing, but you're not redrawing the clock.

Comment: @william.taylor.09 not sure what u mean , what function would u be talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You were incrementing the variable value but you weren't adding the value to the actual displayed hour.

I edited your script and it works now as intended:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 900, 900);
    var backGround = paper.rect(0, 0, 900, 900);
    var incHour = 0;
    var hourBut = paper.rect(404,280, 30,30).attr("fill","white").attr("cursor", "pointer");
    var btnReset = paper.rect(165,280,30,30).attr("fill","white").attr("cursor", "pointer"); 

    hourBut.node.onclick = function() {
        incHour += 1;
    };

    btnReset.node.onclick = function() {
        incHour = 0;
    }



  var face = paper.circle(100, 100, 95);
  face.attr({
    "fill": "#f5f5f5",
    "stroke": "#444444",
    "stroke-width": "10"
  })

  var secondHand = paper.path("M100 110L100 25");
  secondHand.attr({
    stroke: "#ffff00",
    "stroke-width": 2
  });

  var minHand = paper.path('M100,100L99,100L99,20L100,17L101,20L101,100L100,100');
  minHand.attr({
    stroke: "#12184D",
    "stroke-width": 2
  });

  var hourHand = paper.path('M100,100L98,100L98,45L100,40L102,45L102,100L100,100');
  hourHand.attr({
    stroke: "#12184D",
    "stroke-width": 4
  });

  var pin = paper.circle(100, 100, 5);
    pin.attr("fill", "#000000");    

    var startpos;
    var startpos1;
    var endpos;
    var endpos1;
    for(i=0;i<12;i++){
        startpos = 100+Math.round(70*Math.cos(30*i*Math.PI/180));
        startpos1 = 100+Math.round(70*Math.sin(30*i*Math.PI/180));
        endpos = 100+Math.round(90*Math.cos(30*i*Math.PI/180));
        endpos1 = 100+Math.round(90*Math.sin(30*i*Math.PI/180));    
        paper.path('M'+startpos+' '+startpos1+'L'+endpos+' '+endpos1).attr({ stroke: '#cc33ff'});
    }


    var digTime = paper.text(360, 300, "").attr({'font-size': 10, 'fill': 'black', "stroke-width": 1, stroke: "black"});    

    startTime();

  function startTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    var hou = now.getHours();
    var min = now.getMinutes();
    var sec = now.getSeconds();
    var addedHour_byHour = calHourAdded_byHour(incHour);
    if(hou >= 24)
        {
            hou-= 24;   
        }   

    secondHand.animate({
        transform: [ 'r',6 * sec,100,100]
        });

    minHand.animate({
        transform: [ 'r', 6 * min, 100,100]
        }); 

    hourHand.animate({
        transform: [ 'r', 30 * (hou + incHour), 100,100] //added the relevant variable
        });

    digTime.attr("text", (hou + incHour) + ":" + min + ":" + sec); //added the relevant variable

    setTimeout(function() {
      startTime()
    }, 1000);

  }

    function calHourAdded_byHour(hourHand)
    {
        return hourHand%24;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is great thanks but this just made me realize that the if statement does not work

Comment: Might be better to add the hours on to the date before getting all the values used to draw the clock. That would let the JS Date object take care of overflowing to the next day.